Ubuntu 24.04 does not enable my Mac WiFi cards
Ubuntu 24.04 uses a different STA that does not have 802.11 in its title. I have bcm4331 in one Mac and bcm4360 in the 2014 MacBook Air.
Both work with Ubuntu 22.04 and show it is using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA driver source bcmwl-kernel-source.
I tried removing all Broadcom drivers using Synaptic but could not find the driver with 802.11 in the title to install in 24.04. I guess I will try copying the drivers from the USB Live image from the pool folder.
I spent hours reading the volumes of info about the Broadcom cards but just failed.

Did you try and install bcmwl-kernel-source on the system post-install of 24.04?  You may have to hook into an ethernet connection temporarily for that.

tried that also thanks   just couldn't find the right one I am guessing since it did not have 802.11 in the name .   I have to make another 24.04 usb so I can run  24 and 22 side by side on 2 macs to see.

I got this driver from the 22.04 live usb  and it works in 24.04

file:///media/kubuntu/Kubuntu 22.04.5 LTS amd64/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu10~22.04.1_amd64.deb

It looks like bcmwl-kernel-source is actually a transitional package in 24.04 for broadcom-sta-dkms which is what you'd have needed to install along with dkms and other dependencies.  I'm glad the 22.04 package worked, but you may want to consider installing bcmwl-kernel-source and broadcom-sta-dkms from the repositories instead of piece-meal from older sources because there may be updates.
